# Working with touches on a zoomed layer

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, touch, zooming

I have a CCLayerPanZoom subclass. For testing purposes I put a sprite in the middle of the screen. I do the following test before and after zooming:

```
 if(CGRectContainsPoint(mySprite.boundingBox,touchedPoint))
     NSLog(@"Touch inside the sprite");
```

Before zooming I get "Touch inside the sprite" output, but when it's zoomed I don't. I have asked a similar question ([Getting different x and y coordinates for touched location on a zoomed view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18792884/getting-different-x-and-y-coordinates-for-touched-location-on-a-zoomed-view)) and figured it out later. But the solution I found works only for when panning, not for zooming. There're lots of games out there and this must be super simple (at least done prior to me). I need to be able to have the touched point the same as it was before zooming.

Answer (score 0):

I regret all the wasted time to find a way out from this problem. It turns out that there's a neatly packed method called convertToNodeSpace in Cocos2D that lifts all the heavy weight. No need to make all those crazy calculations to take the panned distance and zoomed scale into account. I just did the following and everything worked like a magic

```
touchedPoint=[self convertToNodeSpace: touchedPoint];
```

where self is a subclass of CCLayerPanZoom which is a subclass of CCLayer. That's all. Hope this helps someone.